# One SQL query for filling several JTextfields in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, jtextfield, resultset, fill

I'm working on an application in Java and I would like to fill many `Jtextfield`s using one SQL query.

For example: My query is: `select * from table`, where the table has 2 columns "Items" and "Month":

```
Item  | Month

alpha | 1
beta  | 2
delta | 5
gamma | 3
```

Now i have 4 `JTextfields` `jt1`, `jt2`, `jt3`, `jt4`; and I would like alpha to go in `jt1`, beta to go in `jt2`, gamma to go in `jt3` and `jt4` is empty because for month 4 there's no item.

I have looked for a solution for many days now but I can't find one.

I have this code so far:

```java
String ec = "select * from table";

try {
    Statement stmt_ec = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs_ec = stmt_ec.executeQuery(ec);
    while (rs_ec.next()) {
        // solution ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're taking a wrong way with retrieving the records, you need only *two* textfields since you have two *columns* in the database. So, the number of fields depends on the columns in the database, *not* rows.

```
if(rs_ec.next()){
 itemField.setText(rs_ec.getString("Item");
 monthField.setText(rs_ec.getString("Month");
}
```

In that case, you don't even need to iterate the records as you don't have a table, *textfields* only show one row in a time. If you want all records to be shown, you must use **[JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the while

```
while (rs_ec.next()) {    
    jt1.setText(rs_ec.getString("alpha"));
    jt2.setText(rs_ec.getString("beta"));
    jt3.setText(rs_ec.getString("gamma"));
    jt4.setText(rs_ec.getString("delta"));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but alpha, beta, gamma and delta are not my columns, they are rows when execute the sql query. My columns are Items and Monts

Answer (score 0):

See the `Table From Database Example` code found in [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for some code to create a JTable from an SQL query.